# Iterating over a dictionary using for loop to return price < certain amount

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have completed the function but for some reason it is not returning loans <500 but rather all of them when I output list to csv file... it also returns none when i try to print the list...I know I am doing some thing wrong but not sure exactly what.

Here are the instructions...

1. Create a new, empty list called `inexpensive_loans`.
2. Use a for loop to select each loan from a list of loans.
3. Inside the for loop, write an if-statement to determine if the loan_price is less than or equal to 500
4. If the loan_price is less than or equal to 500 then append that loan to the `inexpensive_loans` list.
   Print the list of inexpensive_loans.

   ```
   loans = [
    {
        "loan_price": 700,
        "remaining_months": 9,
        "repayment_interval": "monthly",
        "future_value": 1000,
    },
    {
        "loan_price": 500,
        "remaining_months": 13,
        "repayment_interval": "bullet",
        "future_value": 1000,
    },
    {
        "loan_price": 200,
        "remaining_months": 16,
        "repayment_interval": "bullet",
        "future_value": 1000,
    },
    {
        "loan_price": 900,
        "remaining_months": 16,
        "repayment_interval": "bullet",
        "future_value": 1000,
    },
   ]

   def inexpensive_loans(loan_price):
       inexpensive_loans = []
       for loan_price in loans.keys('loan_price'): 
           if loan_price <=500:
               print(loan_price, loans [loan_price])
       return inexpensive_loans
       inexpensive_loans.append(loan_price[inexpensive_loans])
   ```

Comment: Can you show "the function"?

Comment: bro i am trying...i can barely format the post...

Answer (score 1):

Im editing my answer as I noticed some more things that will not work with your code.

- Name your function in a precise manner for example `get_inexpensive_loans`. That way it is clear what it does and how it is different from the variable `inexpensive_loans`.
- The parameter `loan_price` in your function definition in the first line is not needed, you get the individual loan prices from the list of loans.
- As Junuxx pointed out, `loans` is an array not a dictionary, so there is no `keys` property and you don't need it. Use `for loan in loans` and access the price for each element by using `loan["loan_price"]`
  You may want to look at [Python For Loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

**Original:**

There are several things that are problematic with your piece of code, I'll go line by line.

- 2nd line: Why do you declare a variable with the same name as the function? I don't know about python but in other languages that can not work properly
- 6th line: Why do you return here? This would end your function at this point
- 7th line: You used your dictionary `inexpensive_loans` as an index to `loan_price` <strike>but you need a number for that</strike>
  `loan_price` is a number, the line should read like `inexpensive_loans.append(loan_price)`

Comment: Does this work?

'Inexpensive_Loans=[]
def inexpensive_loans(loan_price):
    for loan_price in loans.keys('loan_price'): 
        if loan_price <=500:
        Inexpensive_Loans.append(loan_price)
'

Comment: 3rd line: `loans` doesn't have a `keys` attribute, so this would fail.

Comment: 7th line: The instructions say to append the loan, not the loan price.

Comment: `inexpensive_loans = [] #create new list

for loan_price in loans:
    if (loan_price['loan_price']) <= 500:
        print (loan_price)`

I'm having trouble doing the inexpensive_loans.append(loan) because it needs to be converted to an integer right?

Answer (score 0):

Your function has several confused bits to it, which I'll try to fix and describe in comments:

```
def inexpensive_loans(loan_list):
    inexpensive_loans = []   # this variable is OK, but ideally you'd use a different name
    for loan in loan_list:   # you have a list of dicts, you can't directly get the prices
        if loan["price"] <=500:  # instead, get it here by indexing the dict
            inexpensive_loans.append(loan)  # append the dictionary we've iterated to
    return inexpensive_loans # this needs to be unindented to happen outside the loop

print(inexpensive_loans(loans))
```

The instructions you show say to print the list, but I preserved good functional behavior by having the funciton `return` the list it had made and put the `print()` call outside the function where we call it. You could replace `return inexpensive_loans` with `print(inexpensive_loans)` if the function needs to do the printing directly (in that case, you wouldn't use `print()` where you call the function).